# Does a gate driver sink more current due to the Miller Effect?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I have a MOSFET (G2R1000MT33J) that is switching 1000V.  When I switch the MOSFETs at a high frequency with no Vds voltage, the gate driver can handle the thermal load of the switching, but when I switch the MOSFETs with Vds at 1000V, the gate driver quickly become way to hot and turn themselves off in safe mode.  My question is, is this extra thermal load coming from the Miller Effect current that the gate driver is having to sink and deal with?

My mental model of the Miller Effect is a capacitor between the drain and the gate of the MOSFET and the current that the gate driver has to sink is C*dV/dt.  Where C is Crss in the graph below.  Im trying to model this simply in SPICE and I see that Crss changes quite substantially.  So my 2nd question is would I use 70pF (0Vds) of 2.5pF(1000Vds) as the Miller capacitance?

[image]

Comment: Not what you asked, but switching a MOSFET at 100 % rated DC bus voltage is a recipe for disaster in mass production. It may work for a while on your bench though.

Comment: You can’t use a constant capacitor to model this kind of behavior. SPICE models for MOSFETs are designed to handle this non-linear behavior. Or you can define your own non-linear capacitor equation, but why redo all that work?